# Find all the integers $n$ with $22\mid n^2+n-2$

Tags: divisibility

> Find all the integers $n$ with $22\mid n^2+n-2$

I have tried gcd but I have no idea how to solve this

Thank you :)

Comment: Right. What did you try? (And this seems quite easy.)

Comment: I have tried gcd but I have no idea how to solve this

Comment: Please show us what working you have done towards this question. As it stands, this looks very much like a homework question and people here don't take too kindly to being asked to solve homework problems for users

Comment: Well it's always divisible by $2$ so you just need to check if it's divisible by $11$.  If nothing else, you can check the $11$ cases.

Comment: @abiessu They are the same...

Comment: This is practice question, we have learned this for the first time and I go to the practice book and stucked with this one

Comment: @parcly taxel in the original they were not, just wanted to make sure the OP agrees with the new version... (Seems like this version must be correct given the problem as listed, but just to make sure)

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Note that $n^2+n-2$ is really $(n+2)(n-1)$ which is always divisible by $2$, and only by $11$ when $n\equiv1$ or $9\mod11$.